# ebay-api "findItemsByKeywords" pagination in codigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, ebay-api

Can anyone help me with this issue?
I'm making an API call with 50 entries per page.
I get results, but how can i display the next page ?
How to use pagination ? i don't have a clue where to start.
I really need some help here.
Thanks

This is the controller

```
    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        $aaa = $_POST['kikozasearch'];
    }else {
        $aaa = $_POST['kikozasearch'];
    }
    // API request variables
    $endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
    $version = '1.0.0';  // API version supported by your application
    $appid = '';  // Replace with your own AppID
    $globalid = 'EBAY-US';  // Global ID of the eBay site you want to search (e.g., EBAY-DE)
    $query = $aaa;  // You may want to supply your own query
    $safequery = urlencode($query);  // Make the query URL-friendly
    $i = '0';  // Initialize the item filter index to 0

    $apicall = "$endpoint?";
    $apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    $apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=$version";
    $apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appid";
    $apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalid";
    $apicall .= "&keywords=$safequery";
    $apicall .= "&paginationInput.pageNumber=$currentpage";
    $apicall .= "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50";
    //$apicall .= "&paginationOutput.totalPages";
    $apicall .= "$urlfilter";

    // Load the call and capture the document returned by eBay API
    $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

    // Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
    if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
      $results = '';
      // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links  
      foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
        $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
        $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
        $title = $item->title;


        // For each SearchResultItem node, build a link and append it to $results
        $results .= "<div><img src=\"$pic\"></td><td><a href=\"$link\">$title</a>$pag</div>";
      }
    }
    // If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
    else {
      $results  = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
      $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h4></div>";
    }
    echo "We found: ".$resp->paginationOutput->totalEntries . " resaults!";
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>".$results."</div>";
    // echo  $resp->paginationOutput->entriesPerPage;
    // echo "<br>";
    // echo $resp->paginationOutput->totalEntries;
    // echo "<br>";
    // echo $resp->paginationOutput->totalPages;



        echo $currentpage;
        echo "/".$resp->paginationOutput->totalPages;
        echo "<br />";


    $totalpages = $resp->paginationOutput->totalPages;
```

Here is the post request

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#form').on('submit', function(info){
            info.preventDefault();
                $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ebayapps/searchitem',
                        $('#form').serialize(),
                        function(data){
                            $('#resaults').html(data);
                        }
                 );


        }); // keyup
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is my page examle : https://kikoza.com/index.php/ebayapps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to load more than one page of results. In this case, you will need to make numerous API requests, depending on the total number of pages you wanted to retrieve in the first place.

So say you want four pages - you need to run your function four times and increment `paginationInput.pageNumber` in each loop.

I hope this helps.